# Using System.Data.SqlConnection in mono, Second invalid login attempt results in "object reference not set to instance of an object"

Tags: mono, sqlconnection, system.data

Using mono's System.Data.SqlConnection to try to establish a new connection (via prompt to user for username and password), if the user enters the wrong username more than once i get an exception: "object reference not set to instance of an object" when i call MyConnection.Open() on second try and beyond.  I should get a more detailed exception message, ideally similar to first error response which says the username/password combination is invalid or something to that extent.

This appears to be a mono error, but i could be wrong.

Some relevant details: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, 2.10.8.1 appears (from synaptic) to be version of mono-devel package installed.

Here's some code with comment interspersed, and remember, i never claimed it was good code:

```
protected void LoginClick (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    SQLConn = "Data Source=<datasrc goes here>;Initial Catalog=<database name goes here>;User ID=" + UserText.Text + ";Password=" + PassText.Text +  ";MultipleActiveResultSets=True;";//the problem is not in the connection string; it logs in right with the right user/pass

MyConnection=null;
    try
    {
            MyConnection = new SqlConnection(SQLConn);
            ShowMessage("test1");   
            MyConnection.Open();
            ShowMessage("test2");
```

... there's more but it never gets to test2 marker unless i enter valid user/password, it always gets to test1 marker..
...

```
    }
catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if  (MyConnection!=null){
            MyConnection.Close();
        }
        ShowMessage("Error logging into Database: "+ex.Message);    
    }
```

If you need to know for debugging what ShowMessage() looks like i'll include it:

```
public void ShowMessage(string Msg){
        Gtk.MessageDialog md=new Gtk.MessageDialog(this,DialogFlags.Modal,MessageType.Error,ButtonsType.Ok,Msg);
        md.Run();
        md.Destroy();
}
```

This is my first post here, please redirect me if i'm using this site wrong.

My question: 
Am i doing something wrong, or should i report a bug with mono-project?

Comment: Update:  I've not only filed a bug report on this (#4786?), but i've also gone ahead and fixed this today.  I submitted a patch via github and with any luck it'll be accepted and years from now the patch will make it to my local ubuntu install ;->